# Football DB Help

Tags: database-design, normalization

Can anyone let me know how to normalise this, I'm  stuck on the home/away team bit. Cheers

> TEAM(**Team_id**,TeamName)
>
> PLAYER(**Player_id**,FirstName,LastName,DOB)
>
> CONTRACT(**Player_id,Team_id**,StartDate,EndDate,SqaudNumber)
>
> FIXTURE(**Fixture_id**,Ref_id,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,Date)
>
> REFEREE(**Ref_id**,FirstName,LastName)
>
> DISCIPLINARY CASE(**DCase_id**,Player_id,Fixture_id,Event)

Comment: I'm with Derek -- I'm not sure what part you are stuck on, can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine to me as long as HomeTeam and AwayTeam refer to TEAM.Team_id

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question